# How to detect revoke event in telethon?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

If the client is revoked from another device, how can the revoked client know it is offline now?

Which event should I listen for? Or should I do a periodic check?

If I should do a periodic check, which endpoint should I request?

I am using Telethon Library .

Comment: There is no event. A exception will raise through `run_until_disconnected`.

Comment: @Lonami I tried to catch the exception with the following code, but it doesn't seems to work.
`try:
    await client.run_until_disconnected()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`
But, when I terminate the session from my phone, I don't get any exception. Also, all event handlers stop working. What am I doing wrong..?